# Find common value amongst rows

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table structure with example values:

```
Number      Reference                 Length                                  Quantity
----------- ------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------
16002983    ASH 14                    383.000000                              4
16002983    ASH 14                    1669.000000                             4
16002983    GLAS-NP                   403.000000                              1
16003002    SZR 16                    1402.000000                             1
16003002    Energy Surcharge F        56556.680000                            1
16003256    SZR 14                    726.000000                              1
16003256    Energy Surcharge F        40706.820000                            1
16003256    7283-ASB                  726.000000                              1
16003308    ASH 14                    740.000000                              4
```

The table has, as of now, 742 entries and expands every day.

I need to find a `Reference` that is shared among all `Number`s, if there is any.

How? I don't even know if I need `JOIN`s, `GROUP BY`, something else? I seem to fail at logic here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you need for each reference,count of number

Comment: The `Number` column is a unique identifier. I'd like to have just one result - the `Reference`  that occurs at least once per every different `Number`.

Comment: Not clear to me

Comment: `Number` cannot possibly be a unique identifier in *this* table since it can have duplicate values, as follows from your question.

Comment: @AndriyM you are right, I used a wrong term. `Number` serves as a reference to another table, together with two more columns which are omitted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group by reference, count distinct numbers in each group and compare that to the total count of distinct numbers in the table:

```
SELECT
  Reference
FROM
  dbo.atable
GROUP BY
  Reference
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT Number) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Number) FROM dbo.atable)
;
```

Comment: Simple, straightforward, clean. I like this very much, thank you.